# Creating a TopAppBar for each composable with navigation

Tags: android, kotlin, navigation-drawer, android-jetpack-compose

I am currently using a navigation drawer in jetpack compose, but I have encountered a problem. When I added the navigation drawer to the mainDrawerScreen, it was displaying for every screen I added, in my case it said "Main Menu" for every screen composable when navigated to. This is not ideal.

I decided to remove TopAppBar from mainDrawerScreen and create a seperat scaffold with the TopAppBar for each composable screen. However, now the navigation does not work. I tried to create a trailing lambda for navigation but might have done it the wrong way. Anyone got a suggestion to why it is not opening the navDrawer ? Appreciate the feedback!

MainDrawerSCreen:

```
@SuppressLint("UnusedMaterialScaffoldPaddingParameter")
@Composable
fun MainDrawerScreen() {

   val scaffoldState = rememberScaffoldState(rememberDrawerState(DrawerValue.Closed))
   val scope = rememberCoroutineScope()
   val navController = rememberNavController()


   Scaffold(
       scaffoldState = scaffoldState,
       drawerContent = {

           DrawerHeader()
           DrawerLayout(scope = scope, scaffoldState = scaffoldState , navController = navController)

       }
   ) {
      
       Navigation(navController = navController) // TODO This controls the navigation between different screens
   }
}
```

My seperate created TopAppBar:

```
@Composable
fun TopAppBar1(
   scope: CoroutineScope,
   scaffoldState: ScaffoldState,
   text: String,
   onIconClick: () -> Unit
   ) {
   TopAppBar(

       title = { Text(text = text, fontSize = 18.sp) },
       navigationIcon = {
           IconButton(onClick = {
               scope.launch {
                   withContext(Dispatchers.IO) { // should I keep this coroutine on background thread ?
                       scaffoldState.drawerState.open()
                   }
               }
           }) {
               Icon(
                   Icons.Filled.Menu, "Menu",
                   Modifier.clickable { onIconClick.invoke()})
           }
       },
       backgroundColor = LightBlue,
       contentColor = MaterialTheme.colors.onPrimary,

       )
}
```

ProfileScreen:

```
@SuppressLint("UnusedMaterialScaffoldPaddingParameter")
@Composable
fun ProfileScreen1() {

   val scaffoldState = rememberScaffoldState(rememberDrawerState(DrawerValue.Closed))
   val scope = rememberCoroutineScope()


   Scaffold(
   topBar = {
       TopAppBar1(scope = scope, scaffoldState = scaffoldState, text = "Profile") {
           scope.launch { scaffoldState.drawerState.currentValue }     <----------- Trailing Lambda
       }
},
   content = {
       ActualBackground() // Background

       Column(
           modifier = Modifier
               .fillMaxSize(),
           verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Center,
           horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally,
       ) { // Content }
```

Answer (score 0):

I show you what I did :

TopAppBar.kt :

```
@Composable
fun TopAppBarScreen(
    title: String = "",
    screen: String,
    navController: NavController
) {
    TopAppBar(
        title = {
            Text(
                text = title,
                style = Typography.h2
            )
        },
        navigationIcon = {
            IconButton(
                onClick = {
                    navController.navigate(screen)
                }
            ) {
                Icon(Icons.Filled.ArrowBack, "backIcon")
            }
        },
        backgroundColor = Color.Background,
        contentColor = Color.BackgroundDarkGrey,
        elevation = 0.dp,
    )
}
```

Navigation.kt

```
@Composable
fun Navigation() {
    val navController = rememberNavController()
    val viewModel = hiltViewModel<CountrySelectorViewModel>()
    val userViewModel = InputViewModel(LocalContext.current)
    NavHost(
        navController = navController,
        startDestination = Screen.WELCOME_SCREEN
    ) {
        composable(Screen.WELCOME_SCREEN) {
            WelcomeScreen(navController = navController)
        }
}
```

Screen :

```
object Screen {
    const val WELCOME_SCREEN = "WelcomeScreen"
}
```

When I call my TopAppBar :

```
TopAppBarScreen(
        screen = Screen.WELCOME_SCREEN,
        navController = navController
)
```

Look at how the navigation works and it's the same if you are using a button to change screen.

I hope this can help you

Comment: Hello, thanks for the reply! So just 1 thing to clarify cause I might have been a bit vague explained by me, sorry! I want to be able to open a navigation drawer with the click event, not navigate to a different screen. I tried to implement what you did but I am getting 1 problem. It says I need a Job instead of a string in the screen constructor inside TopAppBarScreen

Comment: this is what I tried to do: TopAppBarScreen(title = "Search", navController = navController, screen = scope.launch { scaffoldState.drawerState.open() }), then I get this message: type mismatch.
Required:
String
Found:
Job

Comment: Try probably to change in the TopAppBar.kt screen, because for me screen is a String but For you a job. The thing strange is that a scope is something doing next to the app. I don't know how to for a navigation drawer. I'm going to search and try to help you.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JLICaBEiJS0 Try to do this, and you can watch all his tutorial it's helping me a lot to learn jetpack compose

Comment: Appreciate it! I already watched that video a few times :P, but my navigation problem seem a bit more complex than explained in the video.

Comment: I somehow have to be able to call scaffold.drawerstate.open() but I cant do this without using scope.launch { } which requres me to pass it wihtin the TopAppBar

Comment: Do you have a git repo for your project I can check and try to find a solution

Comment: No, sorry, not for this project though. This works similar to any navigation Drawer out there so If you figure something out though, just let me know here and I will try it out! :)

Comment: The problem is that when you give your scaffoldState at your TopBar, your TopBar to send it back to you activity, you have to use ViewModel. But I'm trying and I can't really find the solution yet

Comment: ohhh I see, I will look into implementing a viewmodel then and see if that helps with the navigation drawer

Comment: you can try this when you call AppBar : AppBar(
                             onNavigationIconClick = {
                                 scope.launch {
                                     scaffoldState.drawerState.open()
                                 }
                             }
                         )

Comment: Idk why with the viewModel it doesn't change

Comment: https://github.com/lerey34/NavigationDrawer If you want to see What I did

Comment: alright will give it a try!

Comment: I tried implementing similar into my project but without success so far

Comment: im thinking, maybe there is a way to use the same topappbar but we configure a title seperate, for every composable screen within a navHost ?